# When a user clicks or select the user profile picture in Django, user details should appear

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

When I select or click the logged user profile image, a multivaluedict key error appears. I want to be able to show and edit user details.
when I call objects.all() it shows all user details,but I need only logged user detail

[image: Error message]

Here is my view.py

```
def profile(request):
    if request.session.has_key('id'):
        uid = request.GET['profileid']
    
        profile = registertb.objects.get(id=uid)
        return render(request, 'profiles.html', {'profile': profile})
```

And here is my html code:

```
<body>
{% if request.session.id %}
    {% for profile in profile %}
    <form action="/myprofile/?profileid={{ profile.id }}/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div id="profile-container">
            <input type="file" id="image-input" name="user_image" accept="image/*" onchange="displayUserProfile()">
            <img id="profile-image" src="{{ profile.user_image.url }}" alt="Profile Picture">
            
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ profile.User_name }}" placeholder="Your Name" required>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="{{ profile.email }}" placeholder="Your Email" required>

            <!-- Other profile fields -->

            <button type="submit">Update Profile</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        function displayUserProfile() {
            var input = document.getElementById('image-input');
            var image = document.getElementById('profile-image');
            
            // Assuming you're using FileReader to read the selected image
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                image.src = e.target.result;
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    </script>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

So this my code

Comment: Please share the full error message.

Comment: Hi, there i have updated the code

Comment: Why do you put the `profileid` in the GET parameter ? Can other users see other profiles ?

Comment: We need the retirev ID from the database, and it needs to match the logeed user ID, so I used the GET parameters function.
And can you define this question " Can other users see other profiles ?"?